# Get cached documentsnapshot localWriteTime

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to do pagination on some offline data.

at the start, I am ordering 10 records by the time

```
myRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10)
```

then when the user scrolls down I get the time of the latest index and start after it like this

```
myRef.orderBy("time",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10).startAfter(latestDocumentTime).get()
```

the "Time" field gets its value from

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

I allowed my users to post things while offline, and this is causing trouble, if the latestDocument still has a pending write then the "time" value will be null.
I tried getting the message before the latestDocument if the latestDocument time  is equal to null, but what if all of the 10 documents that I load at the start have pending writes (their time is null), I looked around the documentSnapshot and I found that it has a localWriteTime variable which I can use as a start point for my query.

How can I get the localWriteTime of DocumentSnapShot?

[here is an Image](https://ibb.co/129Thn4)

Comment: Please show us the code you have and why it's not working as expected. Users here help edit code, not write it from scratch.

Comment: As you can see inside the debugger the document snapshot class has a field called localWriteTime, I am trying to access that variable if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my problem, you can get the estimated write time of the document with

```
val  myTime  = snapshot.get("time", DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior.ESTIMATE) as Timestamp
```

"time" is the name of the field in the document that has the FieldValue.serverTimestamp() value

this will get you the time stamp, you can get the second and nanosecond with

```
 val myTime = snapshot.get("time", DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior.ESTIMATE) as 
 val second = myTime.seconds
 val nano = myTime.nanoseconds
```

I should mention that this time is estimated and the value will change when the snapshot is uploaded to the server